# Can't print all numbers from thread that iterates over natural numbers

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Test {

    static int i = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread(() -> {

            long timer = System.nanoTime();

            while (true) {

                while (System.nanoTime() - timer > 1E9 / 60) {

                    i++;
                    timer = System.nanoTime();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        long timer = System.nanoTime();

        while (true) {

            while (System.nanoTime() - timer > 1E9 / 60) {

                System.out.println(i);
                timer = System.nanoTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you start the program the following will be printed in the console:

```
1,3,4,5,6
```

Why does the number `2` get skipped? I do not think that it is a timing issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Also the keyword volatile in the int can help in those situations

Comment: Why don't you think it has to do with timing? The code is classically thread-unsafe and begs for race conditions. It might reproduce the same behavior on your machine by coincidence. If I switch the two last lines it prints 2 on my machine.

Comment: It is a timing issue.

Comment: Why would you expect *all* the numbers to be printed without any form of synchronization between the thread that generates the numbers and the thread that prints them? The only thing that you can be certain of is that the numbers will be monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Without any synchronisation, this is an example of valid execution (Thread 1 is the thread you create, Thread 2 is the main thread):

```
Thread 1     Thread 2
i = 2
             print i: 2
i = 3
             print i: 3
             print i: 3  //loop iterates twice in Thread 2
i = 4
i = 5                    //loop iterates twice in Thread 1
             print i: 5
i = 6
             print i: 5 //main thread doesn't see the update
i = 7
             print i: 5 //main thread doesn't see the update
```

Note that another valid execution, for example, would be to repeatedly print 1.

Answer (score 2):

The output `1,3,4,5,6` doesn't seem to be constant. It may vary due to improper synchronisation.

The reader prints the value when it obtains it. It doesn't care whether the value has been updated or how many times this value has been updated.

The writer changes the value independently of the reader. It doesn't care about the last value the reader has read.

---

There is a common problem in multithreading called [the readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem). You reproduced the simplest kind of this issue: *one reader to one writer*.

---

You ran identical pieces of code in parallel probably assuming they could some kind "overlay" each other as follows:

```
while (true) {
    while (System.nanoTime() - timer > 1E9 / 60) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        timer = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it never works that way.

There is no ["happened-before"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) relation, therefore there is no guarantee the *"increment-then-print"* or *"print-then-increment"* patterns will always work.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. because the `static int i` variable is used by two different threads
   simultaneously causing unpredictable behaviors due to race
   condition. This problem is solved replacing `static int i` with
   `static AtomicInteger i`
2. `System.nanoTime() - timer > 1E9 / 60`
       will not execute the code in the while loop at exactly predictable
       times.